# Which of these Magento statements is correct?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I am doing some `M2 fundamentals online training`, the system is telling me that one of these answers is incorrect...

**Question 1:** Which of these directives will assign a template to a block in a `layout xml` file

**Answer 1 :** `<block template="test.phtml">`

**Question 2 :** Which block methods are available in a template?

**Answer 2 :** Only `public methods`.

I have tested both of these and they both seem to be right. Is it a trick question ?

Can anyone shed some light before I tear my hair out?

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1 :

There are **Three methods** to set template block in `layout.xml`

1)

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name" template="Vendor_Module::file-name.phtml" />
```

2)

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::file-name.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

3)

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::file-name.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

#### Question 2 :

Yes, of course in template you have access juste for the public methods commings from block, exemple `$block->getAnswer()` this method `public function getAnswer()`is declared and you get it from the block associate to this template and it is well **public**, if it was **private** you can't access it because the `private function` is only visible in it's own class.